# Вернуть вкладки для фильтрации вопросов без принятого ответа

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено

Сейчас на странице вопросов можно посмотреть только все вопросы без ответов в случайном порядке.

Надо добавить ссылку на эту страницу https://ru.stackoverflow.com/unanswered

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged?tab=mytags

Comment: @alexolut как туда попасть?

Comment: Вероятно, только по явной ссылке пока.

Comment: @alexolut эта ссылка короче https://ru.stackoverflow.com/unanswered

Comment: А эта ещё короче: https://goo.gl/r4wuxz

Comment: @alexolut она сложная для запоминания

Comment: Да всё просто же ... эр-четыре-дабл-ю-у-х-з

Answer (score 2):

Ссылка появилась шибко быстро. Молодцы!

> [image: без ответа]

> [image: без ответов]